# typescript union types typeguards

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types

I have a snippet like this:

```
function test(): any[] | string {
  return [1,2]
}

let obj: any[]  = test();
```

This gives the following error in vscode:

```
[ts] Type 'string | any[]' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

I understand that I have to put some kind of guard but not able to understand the concept here. Anyone please?

Comment: as you have defined `test` of type `any[] | string` you must define `obj` to `any` or `any[] | string`

Answer (score 0):

Function `test()` returns 'wider' type that `any[]` declared by variable and as typescript so far cannot in advance verify that the function will always return an array instance - it complains. To fix the issue you should actually use the [typeguards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html) you have mentioned, for example

```
function test(): any[] | string
{
    return [1, 2];
}

let val = test();
if (val instanceof Array)
{//no error here
    let obj: any[] = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With type guards, Typescript can narrow down a union type. You can simply use a narrowing condition, but adding a type guard function gives you additional reusability and flexibility:

```
function isAnyArray(value: any[] | string): value is any[] {
    return value instanceof any[];
}
```

So you can do your assignment regularly and then work in the scope provided by your type guard:

```
let obj: string | any[] = test();

if (isAnyArray(obj)) {
    //Use obj here as if it were an any[]
}
```

Since you are using your union at multiple places, you could define a type for it and use it in place of the manual union type:

```
type StringOrAnyArray = string | any[];
//...
function isAnyArray(value: StringOrAnyArray): value is any[] {
    return value instanceof any[];
}
//...
let obj: StringOrAnyArray = test();

if (isAnyArray(obj)) {
    //Use obj here as if it were an any[]
}
```